# PDO ERROR:SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Help me with the error below please:

> ERROR:SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':username,
>   `oncall_area` = :oncall_area, `oncall_month`  = :oncall_mo' at line 2

My code is:

```
try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $dbuser, $dbpass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "
UPDATE `oncall_users` 
   SET `username`       = :username,
       `oncall_area`    = :oncall_area,
       `oncall_month`   = :oncall_month,
       `oncall_year`    = :oncall_year,
       `oncall_day`     = :oncall_day,
       `order`          = :order,
       `mobile`         = :mobile,
       `email`          = :email,
       `ext`            = :ext,
        WHERE `id`      = :id";

$update = $db->exec($sql);

$update->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update->bindParam(':oncall_area', $oncall_area);
$update->bindParam(':oncall_month', $oncall_month);
$update->bindParam(':oncall_year', $oncall_year);
$update->bindParam(':oncall_day', $oncall_day);
$update->bindParam(':order', $order);
$update->bindParam(':email', $email);
$update->bindParam(':mobile', $mobile);
$update->bindParam(':ext', $ext);
$update->bindParam(':id', $id);

$count = $update->execute();
$db = null;        // Disconnect
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "ERROR:" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: does your user have update privilege on tables?

Comment: what is `$db->exec($sql);`?? does this prepare the statment or what does it do?

Comment: Is that wrong ? thank you

Comment: even when I use prepare it is get the same error

Comment: I would like to update my database.

Answer (score 2):

You have an additional comma here:

```
`ext` = :ext,
```

replace by:

```
`ext` = :ext
```

this is what's causing your issue.

Comment: Appreciate your help Thank you